# How to connect data

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on data `elo_blatter` from the the `fivethirtyeight` package. 
I want to show data about the sources of `gdp` and `population`
I made this code for ex for gdp:

```
gdps <- elo_blatter %>% group_by(gdp_source) %>% summarise(n = n())
```

result is

[image]

How can i connect all CIA data into one?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the rows which has "CIA" in it using `grep`/`grepl`.

```
library(dplyr)

elo_blatter %>% 
  group_by(gdp_source = replace(gdp_source, grep('CIA', gdp_source), 'CIA')) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())
```

You can also do this in `count` :

```
elo_blatter %>% 
    count(gdp_source = replace(gdp_source, grep('CIA', gdp_source), 'CIA'))
```

---

In base R we can use `table` :

```
table(transform(elo_blatter, gdp_source = replace(gdp_source, 
                             grep('CIA', gdp_source), 'CIA'))$gdp_source)
```